# How to compute the result of 8086 IDIV instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Instructions (numbers in hex):

```
mov ax, 0832
mov cx, 008a
idiv cl
```

Documentation says:

```
when operand is a byte:
AL = AX / operand
AH = remainder (modulus)
```

Source: http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#IDIV

As far as I understand, I have to check if the leftmost bit isn't 1:

```
0832 -> 0000.1000.0011.0010
008a -> 0000.0000.1000.1010
```

Since there's no 1's in highest bits, by using calculator I should get:

`0832 mod 008a` as remainder and `0832 div 008a` as `div` part. `Mod` goes to `AH` and `div` should go to `AH`, but I can't get the correct answer. The correct answer is `5CEF`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 for reading the documentation :)

Note that you need to check the leftmost bit according to the effective operand size. Since you are dividing by `CL`, which is a 8 bit value, you need to check bit #7, which is `1`. As such, the number in `CL` is negative, namely `-118`. So,

```
AL = 0832h / -118 = 2098 / -118 = -17 = EFh
AH = 2098 - (-17 * -118) = 92 = 5Ch
```